# Entity framework sqlquery

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, querying

I read about querying database using the entity framework

```
var result = _dbContext.SqlQuery<string>(sql, someParamSqlParameter).ToList();
```

What if i wanted multiple columns to be returned how could i write that type of query.
I tried this code but it gives some sql schema mapping error

```
var result = clsGlobalObjectRefrances.SchoolSoulController.Stt.Database.SqlQuery<LocalAccGroups>(sqlQuery).ToList();
var sqlQuery = "Select GroupId,GroupName,Level from cte_AccGroups";
```

Where LocalAccGroups is a class i created

```
class LocalAccGroups
    {
        public decimal GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        int Level { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanxxx in Advance

Comment: What are the columns returned by your query ? If it is returning Level, then you should mark it as `public` in your class

Comment: It's pretty important to post your query and the definition of your table in the database.  The column names and types returned by your query need to be identical to the object you are deserializing them into.

Comment: Why you not just try to do var result = _dbContext.SqlQuery<LocalAccGroups>(sql, someParamSqlParameter).ToList(); !?

Comment: Ok wait i am editing my question and giving the query i used

Comment: @Habib is there any different between DBContext.SqlQuery and Database.SqlQuery ?

Comment: @BassamAlugili The first query is the one i read somewhere else then the second query is the one i wrote in my code. So i cant use the first query obviously because my Entity model has different names and all stuff like that

Comment: You also need to define the query before you use it. The var sqlQuery line should be before the var result line. That's probably just a typo because it wouldn't compile like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning `Level` as well, and you haven't marked your property `Level` in your class as public.  Mark your property as public and it should be good. Also make sure that the data type matches the one returned by query. It seems odd go a `GroupId` to be of type decimal.

```
class LocalAccGroups
{
    public decimal GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: class should be also public ?

Comment: then what should i declare groupId as

Comment: @BassamAlugili, not really, if both the class and query are in the same namespace.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi, check the data type in database, Go to table, Column definition and you will see the data type for `GroupId`, chances are that it is of type `int`

Comment: Yeaa i checked it out its numeric(18,0). And i tried the code you just suggested but its giving me this error:
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'AccLedger'. Previously found CLR type 'SchoolSoulLibrary.AccLedger', newly found CLR type 'Accounts.Method.AccLedger'.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi, I am not sure about the error, you may see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a8ea003-c6bc-4fc6-ad2a-634f09447c49/ef4-mapping-of-clr-type-to-edm-type-is-ambiguous-error?forum=adodotnetentityframework